# Python bottle module causes "Error: 413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: python, http, bottle

Using Python's module `bottle`, I'm getting HTTP 413 error when posting requests of body size > `bottle`'s internal `MEMFILE_MAX` constant. Minimal working example is shown below.

Server part (`server.py`):

```
from bottle import *

@post('/test')
def test():
    return str(len(request.forms['foo']));

def main():
    run(port=8008);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

Client part (`client.py`):

```
import requests

def main():
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8008/test';

    r = requests.post(url, data={ 'foo' : 100000 * 'a' });
    print(r.text);

    r = requests.post(url, data={ 'foo' : 200000 * 'a' });
    print(r.text);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

The first request prints:

```
100000
```

The second request prints:

```
...
<body>
    <h1>Error: 413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
    <p>Sorry, the requested URL <tt>&#039;http://127.0.0.1:8008/test&#039;</tt>
       caused an error:</p>
    <pre>Request to large</pre>
</body>
....
```

I have absolutely no idea how to increase the `bottle`'s internal limit. Is there any simple way to increase the limit, allowing requests of size, e.g., 1 MB?

Comment: Try changing `bottle.BaseRequest.MEMFILE_MAX` to something larger than `102400`.

Comment: I love that number 102,400. It is so meaningful.

Comment: @vy32 Actually it's a bit less arbitrary than it [looks](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/commit/cb0cacd602c7fdf1a63a44299a206ab6acf8dc57#diff-ad8cb2f640fd3a70db3fc97f3044a4e6R1360).

Comment: Thanks. That's really funny. `#TODO Should not be hard coded...`. And now it no longer is!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should be able to just

```
import bottle
bottle.BaseRequest.MEMFILE_MAX = 1024 * 1024 # (or whatever you want)
```

This appears to be the only way based on the [source](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py)

Comment: Exactly solves my problem! I had a suspicion that I'll have to access the ``MEMFILE_MAX`` property somehow, but wasn't sure at all. Thanks!

Comment: And another stack overflow-user saved my day :) Just for the sake of matter: value comes in byte, standard size is 102400 (as the source from your link also mentioned)

Comment: you sir, made my day